# Searching a Facebook User's Timeline

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-timeline

I'm executing this FQL query to search the wall posts on my own timeline:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+message+FROM+stream+WHERE+source_id=me()%20AND+strpos(message,'metallica')+>0&access_token=XXXX

(Sorry for the link, it didn't appear nice)

Is this not supposed to return all status updates I have that includes the string "metallica"? Am I doing something wrong? The older posts (1-2 years old) don't return. Is this because:

Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >) to retrieve a much greater range of posts.

Comment: I bet the only reason they limit it is so that people dont make a better search than they have. That and it would eat up a LOT of processing and bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read a blog article on how Facebook's queries work (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/)

Say for example I query `SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() AND comments.count > 50 LIMIT 10`

1. The initial get of stream items is limited to 10 solely based upon what it can fetch using the indexed fields (marked with an asterix on their documentation pages) as well as the LIMIT you specified. Remember, these are the most recent stream items.
2. Then the addition WHERE parts are filtered off of those 10, so if you only had 1 post in those 10 with more than 50 comments, then you're going to get 1 result back.  That sucks, right?

I believe the max limit is 5000, so that'd be your best bet for getting your Metallica posts. However even so, the Graph API seems to be limited in how far back it goes.  Some people have looked and found that posts only going back to 2010 are there, I cannot get past April 2009. Maybe I have fewer postings per year that the others and it might be post count based rather than date based for how much the API will store.

Comment: Thanks for the limit suggestion, I'm setting my limit to 5000 and can reach up to July 2010, now. Not exactly as old as I want it to be, but it's better than nothing I guess.